# Loop not ending

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to loop this if statement until the user inputs the right answer. it does not end when ran even if i put in the right input. Also how do i use the playerPick variable outside of the while loop without messing up the code?

```
System.out.println("Please choose either Applaro, Svartra, Tunholmen, or Godafton.");
boolean temp = true;
    while (temp) {
        String playerPick = console.next();
        if (!playerPick.equals("Applaro") && !playerPick.equals("Svartra") && !playerPick.equals("Tunholmen")
                && !playerPick.equals("Godafton")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid input.");
        } else if (playerPick.equals("Applaro") || playerPick.equals("Svartra") || playerPick.equals("Tunholmen")
                || playerPick.equals("Godafton")) {
            System.out.println("You have picked " + playerPick);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you never change temp to false.

Comment: You do not change the value of `temp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop will continue as long as *temp* is true. In the nested if-statement we set *temp* as false which exits the loop.

As for the *playerPick*: the variable is declared outside of the loop so It should be accessible anywhere within the function that is below the declaration (code is read top down here). If you are trying to access *playerPick* from another method then you will need to declare the variable in the super class.

Note: I also cleaned up your if-statement to make it more readable.

Hope this helps!

```
System.out.println("Please choose either Applaro, Svartra, Tunholmen, or Godafton.");
boolean temp = true;
String playerPick = "";
    while (temp) {
        playerPick = console.next();
        if (playerPick.equals("Applaro") || playerPick.equals("Svartra") || playerPick.equals("Tunholmen") || playerPick.equals("Godafton")) {
            System.out.println("You have picked " + playerPick);
            temp = false;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid input.");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set `temp = false` like example below:

```
System.out.println("Please choose either Applaro, Svartra, Tunholmen, or Godafton.");
    boolean temp = true;
        while (temp) {
            String playerPick = console.next();
            if (!playerPick.equals("Applaro") && !playerPick.equals("Svartra") && !playerPick.equals("Tunholmen")
                    && !playerPick.equals("Godafton")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid input.");
            } else if (playerPick.equals("Applaro") || playerPick.equals("Svartra") || playerPick.equals("Tunholmen")
                    || playerPick.equals("Godafton")) {
                System.out.println("You have picked " + playerPick);
                //here
                temp = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: or use a `break`

Comment: thanks do you know how i would be able to use the playerPick variable outside of the while loop?

Comment: Declare it outside the loop?

Comment: when i do, the program turns into an infinite loop when i run it

Answer (score -1):

This could remove the less readable variable "temp".
 Do while loop would better indicate prompt for user input.
 I think it is more readable to remove the if-else clause in the while loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String prompt = "Please choose either Applaro, Svartra, Tunholmen, or Godafton.";
    String playerPick = null;
    try (Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        do {
            System.out.println(prompt);
            playerPick = console.next();                   
            prompt = "Please enter a valid input.";
        } while (!playerPick.equals("Applaro") && !playerPick.equals("Svartra") && !playerPick.equals("Tunholmen") && !playerPick.equals("Godafton"));
        System.out.println("You have picked " + playerPick);

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid input.");
    }        
}
```